# Google Chrome Messing Up Navigation Menus When Zooming

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zooming

This used to work fine in google chrome until recently and works in all other browsers.

For some reason when I zoom in and out with google chrome the borders on my top navigation buttons get distorted.  A dark line appears between each one.  Also, my leftmost button wraps to the next line while zooming.  Can anyone provide any insight into why this is happening?

Can anyone provide any tips as to how I can prevent the brands tab from moving so much when zooming?  I am using em for font size, but I know no matter what it is going to move around.  I could just center the whole ul, but is there a cleaner way to hide this?

http://dev.gerhardsappliance.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of the problem comes with the amount of images you're using. You could simplify your menu immensely by both spriting your images and also using the CSS to work for you.

For example, the lines between your spans wouldn't be visible if, instead of running your .topNavC with a background image, run the li itself (or even the whole ul) with the background image and overlay it with .topNavL and .topNavR backgrounds when needed. You can accomplish this menu look with two or even one image.

When you zoom, all these images are being forced into pixel ratios they don't necessarily fit. I would use CSS for the blue borders and white backgrounds instead of images anyway.

Comment: Consider adding the background images like so: ul.topNavC, li.topNavL, and a.topNavR with the necessary padding for each. Then dump your spans.